# DIsplay value of a variable in JSTL c:out

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<%! int b=10; %>
            <c:out value="${b}"/>
```

How to display value of this variable 'b' in JSP JSTL c:out.
I tried the above code but it doesn't show the value of b.

I have the jar & taglib as required  jstl 1.2.jar

Comment: Add it to the request as an attribute called `b` first. So `request.setAttribute("b", b)`

Comment: Now this is working.